# how to Redirecting to a fragment class from the activity class (onOptionsItemSelected)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing a android application,so when i'm in the  developing process i have some trouble in the fragment classes.

i have two class ,
Class A Is a activity class and class B is a Fragment class

When i'm in the Activity A  class i want to back to the Fragment B class i use the onOptionsItemSelected for redirect to the fragment class.

i try several ways to achive this,unfortunatly i can't do this.is any one can help to me it's very big help to me.

here is my code

```
    @Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent GotoFragmentB= new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivity(GotoFragmentB);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for going intent to fragment;

```
  FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  tx.replace(R.id.frame_layout_id, new ENTER_Fragment_NAME());
  tx.commit();
```

Comment: what you mean (R.id.frame_layout_id)  it's layout name ?

Comment: No its your FrameLayout's id

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

try

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().
                beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, new HomeFragment());
        transaction.commit();
```

here `R.id.frame_layout` is id of that layout which you are replacing with  fragment

FOR More information https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm